# Rails - Place Condition On Join With Includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, rails-activerecord

I'm using Rails 3.2.9 and attempting to return all the results of a `categories` table to any matching results of a `incomes` table that is filtered by a department_id on the join.  The SQL query is fairly simple:

```
SELECT * FROM categories LEFT OUTER JOIN incomes ON incomes.category_id = categories.id AND dept_id = 86
```

Now I've been able to achieve the desired results with a `joins`:

```
Category.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN incomes ON incomes.category_id = categories.id AND incomes.dept_id = 86')
```

But I don't know why I couldn't get this to work with an `include`. Below are my models:

**Category**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cat_code, :cat_ds
  has_many :incomes, :conditions => ['dept_id = ?', 86]                   
end
```

**Income**

```
class Income < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_id, :year_id,:dept_id, :note
  belongs_to :category
end
```

I have attempted many different ways to be able to get the desired results, but I will illustrate my latest try, with the above models.

```
@cat_inc = Category.find(:all, :include => [:incomes])
```

But I'm getting a `undefined method each for nil:NilClass` when attempting to `debug(@cat_inc)`

I'm confused why the above doesn't produce the above SQL statement.  Any ideas?

**EDIT**
Perhaps a better way to phrase this, how can I have a condition on a join? Like the above SQL statement has: `AND dept_id = 86`

The closest I could get was:

```
Category.includes(:incomes).where("incomes.dept_id = ?", 86)
```

This gives me the LEFT OUTER JOIN but performs the condition `AND dept_id = 86` after the join.

```
SELECT "categories"."id" AS t0_r0, "categories"."cat_code" AS t0_r1, "categories"."cat_ds" AS t0_r2, "incomes"."id" AS t1_r0, "incomes"."category_id" AS t1_r1, "incomes"."year_id" AS t1_r2, "incomes"."chart_id" AS t1_r3, "incomes"."dept_id" AS t1_r4, "incomes"."note" AS t1_r5, "incomes"."jan" AS t1_r6, "incomes"."feb" AS t1_r7, "incomes"."created_at" AS t1_r8, "incomes"."updated_at" AS t1_r9 FROM "categories" LEFT OUTER JOIN "incomes" ON "incomes"."category_id" = "categories"."id" WHERE (incomes.dept_id = 86)
```

Comment: You should immediately upgrade your app to **3.2.11**. The updates contain nothing but multiple **extremely critical security fixes**. http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: @Deefour- thank you! I'm aware of the vulnerability, but this is only a test application for now.  I appreciate the concern though.

Comment: `.joins` and `.include` are 2 very different things. What exactly is the issue you're having?

Comment: @Deefour - I'm essentially trying to get a conditional join like `AND incomes.dept_id = 86` on an `:includes`.  I've attempted to do this on the association, but I get a undefined method as above.  Just trying to figure out why. Am I looking at this the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think has_many should have pluralize word of class. Check out the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Thank you Anand for catching my mistake.  Unfortunately, it still produces the same error when fixed.

Comment: I think there would not be any array in :include. i.e it should like :include => :income

Comment: I don't think there is any possible way to add a condition on the join, only after the join with an `includes`.  I've fixed the array and still the same results.